# Spring boot Context initialization failed exception

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-boot, soap

I'm getting this exception and unable to solve it. Also, unable to find the root cause this exception. The same code is working in another project, with less dependencies. Why this is happening? The versions are the same as I have used in the both projects.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Could not initialize WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter
    at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet.initMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter(MessageDispatcherServlet.java:380) ~[spring-ws-core-4.0.5.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet.initStrategies(MessageDispatcherServlet.java:361) ~[spring-ws-core-4.0.5.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet.onRefresh(MessageDispatcherServlet.java:296) ~[spring-ws-core-4.0.5.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:603) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:537) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:169) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at jakarta.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:143) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:6.0]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.init(HttpServlet.java:121) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:6.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:944) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:662) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:114) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:341) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:894) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1740) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Invocation of init method failed
    at org.springframework.ws.support.DefaultStrategiesHelper.instantiateBean(DefaultStrategiesHelper.java:182) ~[spring-ws-core-4.0.5.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.support.DefaultStrategiesHelper.getDefaultStrategies(DefaultStrategiesHelper.java:135) ~[spring-ws-core-4.0.5.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.support.DefaultStrategiesHelper.getDefaultStrategy(DefaultStrategiesHelper.java:212) ~[spring-ws-core-4.0.5.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet.initWebServiceMessageFactory(MessageDispatcherServlet.java:389) ~[spring-ws-core-4.0.5.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet.initMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter(MessageDispatcherServlet.java:377) ~[spring-ws-core-4.0.5.jar:na]
    ... 25 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.ws.soap.SoapMessageCreationException: Could not create SAAJ MessageFactory: Unable to create SAAJ meta-factory: class com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.SAAJMetaFactoryImpl cannot be cast to class jakarta.xml.soap.SAAJMetaFactory (com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.SAAJMetaFactoryImpl and jakarta.xml.soap.SAAJMetaFactory are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory.afterPropertiesSet(SaajSoapMessageFactory.java:156) ~[spring-ws-core-4.0.5.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.support.DefaultStrategiesHelper.instantiateBean(DefaultStrategiesHelper.java:180) ~[spring-ws-core-4.0.5.jar:na]
    ... 29 common frames omitted
Caused by: jakarta.xml.soap.SOAPException: Unable to create SAAJ meta-factory: class com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.SAAJMetaFactoryImpl cannot be cast to class jakarta.xml.soap.SAAJMetaFactory (com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.SAAJMetaFactoryImpl and jakarta.xml.soap.SAAJMetaFactory are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at jakarta.xml.soap.SAAJMetaFactory.getInstance(SAAJMetaFactory.java:73) ~[jakarta.xml.soap-api-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at jakarta.xml.soap.MessageFactory.newInstance(MessageFactory.java:126) ~[jakarta.xml.soap-api-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory.afterPropertiesSet(SaajSoapMessageFactory.java:139) ~[spring-ws-core-4.0.5.jar:na]
    ... 30 common frames omitted

[2m2023-08-08T17:53:10.852+05:30[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m8736[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8083-exec-1][0;39m [36mo.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Servlet.init() for servlet [messageDispatcherServlet] threw exception

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Could not initialize WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter
    at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet.initMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter(MessageDispatcherServlet.java:380) ~[spring-ws-core-4.0.5.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet.initStrategies(MessageDispatcherServlet.java:361) ~[spring-ws-core-4.0.5.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet.onRefresh(MessageDispatcherServlet.java:296) ~[spring-ws-core-4.0.5.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:603) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:537) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:169) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at jakarta.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:143) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:6.0]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.init(HttpServlet.java:121) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:6.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:944) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:662) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:114) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:341) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:894) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1740) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Invocation of init method failed
    at org.springframework.ws.support.DefaultStrategiesHelper.instantiateBean(DefaultStrategiesHelper.java:182) ~[spring-ws-core-4.0.5.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.support.DefaultStrategiesHelper.getDefaultStrategies(DefaultStrategiesHelper.java:135) ~[spring-ws-core-4.0.5.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.support.DefaultStrategiesHelper.getDefaultStrategy(DefaultStrategiesHelper.java:212) ~[spring-ws-core-4.0.5.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet.initWebServiceMessageFactory(MessageDispatcherServlet.java:389) ~[spring-ws-core-4.0.5.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet.initMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter(MessageDispatcherServlet.java:377) ~[spring-ws-core-4.0.5.jar:na]
    ... 25 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.ws.soap.SoapMessageCreationException: Could not create SAAJ MessageFactory: Unable to create SAAJ meta-factory: class com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.SAAJMetaFactoryImpl cannot be cast to class jakarta.xml.soap.SAAJMetaFactory (com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.SAAJMetaFactoryImpl and jakarta.xml.soap.SAAJMetaFactory are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory.afterPropertiesSet(SaajSoapMessageFactory.java:156) ~[spring-ws-core-4.0.5.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.support.DefaultStrategiesHelper.instantiateBean(DefaultStrategiesHelper.java:180) ~[spring-ws-core-4.0.5.jar:na]
    ... 29 common frames omitted
Caused by: jakarta.xml.soap.SOAPException: Unable to create SAAJ meta-factory: class com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.SAAJMetaFactoryImpl cannot be cast to class jakarta.xml.soap.SAAJMetaFactory (com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.SAAJMetaFactoryImpl and jakarta.xml.soap.SAAJMetaFactory are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at jakarta.xml.soap.SAAJMetaFactory.getInstance(SAAJMetaFactory.java:73) ~[jakarta.xml.soap-api-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at jakarta.xml.soap.MessageFactory.newInstance(MessageFactory.java:126) ~[jakarta.xml.soap-api-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory.afterPropertiesSet(SaajSoapMessageFactory.java:139) ~[spring-ws-core-4.0.5.jar:na]
    ... 30 common frames omitted

[2m2023-08-08T17:53:10.853+05:30[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m8736[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8083-exec-1][0;39m [36ma.c.c.C.[.[.[.[messageDispatcherServlet][0;39m [2m:[0;39m Allocate exception for servlet [messageDispatcherServlet]

jakarta.xml.soap.SOAPException: Unable to create SAAJ meta-factory: class com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.SAAJMetaFactoryImpl cannot be cast to class jakarta.xml.soap.SAAJMetaFactory (com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.SAAJMetaFactoryImpl and jakarta.xml.soap.SAAJMetaFactory are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at jakarta.xml.soap.SAAJMetaFactory.getInstance(SAAJMetaFactory.java:73) ~[jakarta.xml.soap-api-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at jakarta.xml.soap.MessageFactory.newInstance(MessageFactory.java:126) ~[jakarta.xml.soap-api-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory.afterPropertiesSet(SaajSoapMessageFactory.java:139) ~[spring-ws-core-4.0.5.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.support.DefaultStrategiesHelper.instantiateBean(DefaultStrategiesHelper.java:180) ~[spring-ws-core-4.0.5.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.support.DefaultStrategiesHelper.getDefaultStrategies(DefaultStrategiesHelper.java:135) ~[spring-ws-core-4.0.5.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.support.DefaultStrategiesHelper.getDefaultStrategy(DefaultStrategiesHelper.java:212) ~[spring-ws-core-4.0.5.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet.initWebServiceMessageFactory(MessageDispatcherServlet.java:389) ~[spring-ws-core-4.0.5.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet.initMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter(MessageDispatcherServlet.java:377) ~[spring-ws-core-4.0.5.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet.initStrategies(MessageDispatcherServlet.java:361) ~[spring-ws-core-4.0.5.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet.onRefresh(MessageDispatcherServlet.java:296) ~[spring-ws-core-4.0.5.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:603) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:537) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:169) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at jakarta.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:143) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:6.0]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.init(HttpServlet.java:121) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:6.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:944) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:662) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:114) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:341) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:894) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1740) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

Here, is the POM file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>bbpslite</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>bbpslite</name>
    <description>BBPS Lite for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <start-class>com.ci.lite.BliteApplication</start-class>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    <!--    <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency> -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.servlet/jakarta.servlet-api -->


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--
        https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springdoc/springdoc-openapi-ui -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.0</version>
        </dependency>

    <!--    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency> -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.uuid</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-uuid-generator</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
            <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>wsdl4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>wsdl4j</artifactId>
        </dependency> 
    
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version> 
        </dependency> -->
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.xml.ws/jakarta.xml.ws-api -->
<!-- <dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.xml.soap</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.xml.soap-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.2</version>
</dependency>
-->
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.soap/javax.xml.soap-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.soap</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.xml.soap-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.xml.soap</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.xml.soap-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.ws/spring-ws-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.5</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj</groupId>
    <artifactId>saaj-impl</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2</version>
</dependency>

    </dependencies>
    

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>xsd1</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>xjc</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sources>
                                <source>
                                    src/main/resources/xsd/request/customerBBPOUToBBPCU.xsd</source>
                            </sources>
                            <packageName>com.ci.lite.jaxb.request</packageName>
                            <clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                        <execution>
                    <id>xsd2</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>xjc</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sources>
                            <source>src/main/resources/xsd/request/billFetchresponse.xsd</source>
                        </sources>
                        <packageName>com.ci.lite.jaxb.response</packageName>
                        <clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>
                    </configuration>
                 </execution> 
                   <execution>
                    <id>xsd3</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>xjc</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sources>
                            <source>src/main/resources/xsd/request/countries.xsd</source>
                        </sources>
                        <packageName>com.ci.lite.jaxb.countries</packageName>
                        <clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>
                    </configuration>
                 </execution> 
                </executions>

            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

This is config for the SOAP service

```
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.EnableWs;
import org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.WsConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet;
import org.springframework.ws.wsdl.wsdl11.DefaultWsdl11Definition;
import org.springframework.xml.xsd.SimpleXsdSchema;
import org.springframework.xml.xsd.XsdSchema;

@EnableWs
@Configuration
public class SoapWSConfig extends WsConfigurerAdapter {
    @Bean(name = "countries")
    public DefaultWsdl11Definition defaultWsdl11Definition(XsdSchema xsdSchema) {
        DefaultWsdl11Definition wsdl11Definition = new DefaultWsdl11Definition();
        wsdl11Definition.setPortTypeName("CountriesPort");
        wsdl11Definition.setLocationUri("/ws");
        wsdl11Definition.setTargetNamespace("http://spring.io/guides/gs-producing-web-service");
        wsdl11Definition.setSchema(xsdSchema);
        return wsdl11Definition;
    }

    @Bean
    public XsdSchema xsdSchema() {
        return new SimpleXsdSchema(new ClassPathResource("xsd/request/countries.xsd"));
    }
}
```

How could I resolve this?

Comment: did you get your issue resolved?  I just ran into the same error.  One WS method generates this error, another very similar does not.  I see you are using  JDK17, a lot of people have problems upgrading to anything later than JDK8.  May also be the spring boot version?   Looks like you are using the sample code from Spring - so if you have not introduced any changes other than it being in another project, it may be Spring or JDK version related, which does not help my problem with one method in the project causing this error but another (and two other WS methods) not causing it O_o

Comment: It was a dependency issue. The project had missing dependencies like spring-test.